# How to check if a string contains a substring within an array of strings in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a **string** "A very nice beach" and I want to be able to see if it contains any words of the substring within the array of **wordGroups**.

```
let string = "A very nice beach"

let wordGroups = [
    "beach",
    "waterfront",
    "with a water view",
    "near ocean",
    "close to water"
]
```

Comment: So if `string` contains "beaches" is "beach" from `wordGroups` a match then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution is for exactly matching the word or phrase in `wordGroups` using regex

```
var isMatch = false
for word in wordGroups {
    let regex = "\\b\(word)\\b"
    if string.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression) != nil {
        isMatch = true
        break
    }
}
```

As suggested in the comments the above loop can be replace with a shorter `contains` version

```
let isMatch = wordGroups.contains { 
    string.range(of: "\\b\($0)\\b", options: .regularExpression) != nil
}
```

Second solution is for simply text if `string` contains the any of the strings in the array

```
let isMatch2 = wordGroups.contains(where: string.contains)
```

So for "A very nice beach" both returns true but for "Some very nice beaches" only the second one returns true

Comment: why not `contains(where:)` instead of `first(where:)` != nil

Comment: No particular reason really, `first(where)` was the first (duh) one that came to mind but not needing `!= nil` is of course even clearer. Thanks.

Comment: You can still use `contains { ... }` in the first solution

Comment: @Sulthan not sure I understand, wouldn't that make it the same as the second solution?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think the important part of the first solution is the use of regular expression, not the iteration. Therefore you can still use `wordGroups.contains { word in string.range(of: "\\b\(word)\\b", options: .regularExpression) != nil }`

Comment: @Sulthan Ok, thanks. I focused on the wrong part when reading your comment

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't too sure how to interpret "to see if it contains any words of the substring within the array of wordGroups", but this solution checks to see if any words of your input string are contained in any substring of your word groups.

```
func containsWord(str: String, wordGroups: [String]) -> Bool {
    // Get all the words from your input string
    let words = str.split(separator: " ")
    
    
    for group in wordGroups {
        // Put all the words in the group into set to improve lookup time
        let set = Set(group.split(separator: " "))
        
        for word in words {
            if set.contains(word) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    
    return false
}
```